# ReactJs Components - Problema com o button/renderização

Tags: javascript, react, button, component

Eu tenho um `Componente Button` e o mesmo se encontra dentro de outro `componente Main`. O meu propósito era que ao clicar nesse `componente Button`, ele ficasse alternando entre outros componentes visuais dentro do Main.

O Button é como fosse uma espécie de controlador de Componentes e eu gostaria que a cada clique ele mostrasse um comportamento renderizado na tela diferente, mas eu não estou conseguindo fazer do jeito que eu quero.

**Component Main:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import Handlerbutton from './HandlerButton';

class Main extends Component{
  render(){
    return(
     <div className="main" id="main">
      <div className="start">
       <Handlerbutton />
      </div>
    </div>
   );
  }
}
export default Main;
```

**Component Button:**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './style.css';
import StartAnimatedText from './../StartAnimation';
import Photos from './../../Photos';

class Handlerbutton extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nextpage: true,
      page:0,
      component:<StartAnimatedText />,
    }
  }
  handleClick = () => {
    const pageNumber = this.state.page;
    this.setState({ 
      page: this.state.page += 1,
      component: ''
    })
    //console.log(pageNumber);
    if(pageNumber === 0){
      this.setState({
        component: <Photos />
      })
    }
    else if(pageNumber === 1){
      this.setState({
        component: 'Outro componente aqui...'
      })
    }
   }
 render(){
   return (
    <div>
      {this.state.nextpage && this.state.component}
      <button id="btn-start" onClick={this.handleClick}><span>Continuar</span></button>
    </div>
   );
 }
}
export default Handlerbutton;
```

**Component renderizado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Cara coloca o código.

Comment: Pronto @VirgilioNovic

Comment: Viu um exemplo bem básico?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um exemplo minimo de como trocar o `component` mediante alguma condição estabelecida, isso pode dar um norte como fazer isso e agora é com você colocar a sua própria idéia.

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return <div>Home</div>
  }
}
class Source extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return <div>Source</div>
  }
}
class End extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return <div>End</div>
  }
}
class App extends React.Component{  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      component: 'Home'
    }
    this.handleChangeComponent = 
      this.handleChangeComponent.bind(this)
  }
  handleChangeComponent() {  
    let { component } = this.state;    
    if (component === 'Home') {
      component = 'Source';
    } 
    else if (component === 'Source') {
      component = 'End';
    }
    this.setState({component});
  }
  render() {  
    const { component } = this.state;    
    switch (component) {
      case 'Home': {
        return (
          <div>
            <Home/> 
            <button onClick={this.handleChangeComponent}>Next</button>
           </div>
        );
      }
      case 'Source': {
        return (
          <div>
            <Source/> 
            <button onClick={this.handleChangeComponent}>Next</button>
           </div>
        );
      }
      case 'End': {
        return (
          <div>
            <End/> 
           </div>
        );
      }
    }
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Esse exemplo ficou bem simples para o entendimento, mas, outro exemplo:

```js
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return <div>Home</div>
  }
}
class Source extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return <div>Source</div>
  }
}
class End extends React.Component {
  render() {
   return <div>End</div>
  }
}
class App extends React.Component{  
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      component: <Home />
    }
    this.handleChangeComponent = 
      this.handleChangeComponent.bind(this)
  }
  handleChangeComponent() {  
    let {index, component} =
      this.state;
    if (index === 0) {
      index = 1;
      component = <Source />      
    } 
    else if (index === 1)
    {
      index = 2;
      component = <End />
    }
    this.setState({
        index, component
    });
  }
  render() {  
    const { index, component } = this.state;    
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {component}
        {index !== 2 && (
          <button onClick={this.handleChangeComponent}>
            Next
          </button>
        )}
      </React.Fragment>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render( <App/> , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

então tem várias formas de resolver o problema.

Comment: Obg mano, deu uma esclarecida aqui. Então quer dizer q minha resolução tava certa tbm? Mas uma coisa tbm, eu queria q mudasse o style dos componentes.

Comment: @Dominik quase certo. Sobre estilo pode abrir outra pergunta mas isso é só colocar no componente.

Comment: Obg, já fiz a implementação. @Virgilio Novic